# Would a Nictating Membrane make better blackpowder Infantry?

Tags: biology, warfare

From matchlocks to percussion caps muskets and rifles produced (to vary degrees) sparks, smoke, and granules which had the chance to injure the eyes, or even blind, the shooter.   For smoothbore muskets with a "ready-level-fire" command the shooters frequently closed their eyes before pulling the trigger, and even with more accurate rifles from the American Civil War soldiers frequently closed their eyes when shooting to avoid potential injury.

Given all that, would a nictitating membrane similar to ones lizards have (the "third" eyelid that goes sideways across the eye) allow a infantrylizard/mutant/whomever to safely shoot a matchlock/flintlock/percussion cap blackpowder weapon with their eyes open without risk of eye injury?  Or are the membranes usually sensitive to the point where they'd be damaged by sparks to the point where the shooter would be just as incapacitated?  My thought is a unit that could reliably fire with their eyes open would be, at least at the start of a fight before barrels get fouled, more accurate and therefor more effective than "normal" infantrymen.

Comment: Hello, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. When you have a moment, please take our [tour] and visit our [help] (or this [summary of the rules](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8491/40609)) to better understand our site. Can you provide a citation about Civil War soldiers closing their eyes? I know black powder hunters - and they don't. But, more specifically, a nictating membrane would certainly help. It's your world, so you can declare it to be so. What problem are you trying to solve? What about the membranes do you not trust?

Comment: Again. Welcome Dario for the nth time. There's no shame in rolling-up your sleeves and registering this time. (You might be able to help-out with the review queues after gaining the rep). Translucent they are, transparent might be a sticking point.

Comment: Every time you ask or answer a question from a new temp-account you generate a new first post review action. It would reduce the amount of noise in that queue if you stuck with one account.

Comment: I don't trust that they'd provide sufficient protection from sparks, and now based on Rouge Ant's response, if they're transparent enough to see through anyway!  As to citations, I believe it's mentioned in the memoir "Company Aytch" and is something I was instructed in anecdotally when I made a brief foray into civil war reenacting.  Though I admit the sourcing is much more prevalent in matchlock/flintlocks.

Comment: Could we have a cite for the allegation that it was the sparks from black powder weapons that caused the closing of the eyes, not mere human nature of flinching at a flash and loud noise?

Answer (score 1):

For sure a membrane is sensitive, as any living part, but it's a tradeoff. Have you ever seen in a football match (soccer if you are American) when the players in a barrier against a free kick cover their sensitive parts with their hands? Well, hands are sensitive too and hurt if hit, but hurt less than the part they are protecting.

A similar concept would apply for the nictating membrane: even if it hurts when scratched, it would be less harmful than the same damage on the surface of the eye. However the membrane is not perfectly transparent, therefore it would still somehow affect the vision at the moment of firing, though less than completely shutting the eyelids.